# Crossfading the background-image of a single element without script

Tags: html, css

I want to switch background image of the body periodically, cross fading between each image.

A script solution would look like this:

css:

```
body
{
    background-image: url("img/1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transition: background-image 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

js:

```
var images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg"];
var current_image = 0;
$(function ()
{
    var body = $("body");
    setTimeout(next, 10000);

    function next()
    {
        current_image = (current_image + 1) % images.length;
        body.css("background-image", "url('img/" + images[current_image] + "')");

        setTimeout(next, 10000);
    }
});
```

But is it possible to cross fade the background of a single element (as opposed to change opacities of a number of img elements) using no scripting?

Comment: Have a look at keyframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you could do it with css animations.

something like this.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box}

.slides {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: tomato;
  animation: images 4s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes images {
  0% {
    background: url('https://fillmurray.com/300/300')
  }
  
  50% {
   background: url('http://www.placecage.com/c/300/300');
  }
  
  100% {
    background: url('https://stevensegallery.com/300/300')
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slides"></div>
```

Comment: I accepted this answer and wrote a complementary one.

Answer (score 1):

I post this as an answer to my own question even if there is a solution that I accepted. What this will add is how to stay for a while on the same image without immediately transitioning to the next.

```
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  animation: images 100s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes images {
  0% {
    background-image: url("img/1.jpg")
  }

  19% {
    background-image: url("img/1.jpg")
  }

  20% {
    background-image: url("img/2.jpg");
  }

  39% {
    background-image: url("img/2.jpg");
  }

  40% {
    background-image: url("img/3.jpg");
  }

  59% {
    background-image: url("img/3.jpg");
  }

  60% {
    background-image: url("img/4.jpg");
  }

  79% {
    background-image: url("img/4.jpg");
  }

  80% {
    background-image: url("img/5.jpg");
  }

  99% {
    background-image: url("img/5.jpg");
  }

  100% {
    background-image: url("img/1.jpg")
  }
}
```

I tried to group some percentages like

```
0%, 19%, 100% {
  background-image: url("img/1.jpg");
}
```

but that resulted in "flickering" between images.